# Regex function in R that will only detect first six numbers?

Tags: r, regex

I need to find Regex that has to be implemented in R to detect the first six numbers in this test case and output TRUE/FALSE.

```
test_case = c('401 501', '401-501', '(401)501', '401501', '+401501', '4011501')
```

I've tried this function:

```
str_detect(test_case, regex('^[- + \\d]{6}'))
```

but I can't quite get the outputs to appear as so:

```
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: It's not very clear what the rule is for a match. In the fifth example (+401501), should this return false because it is prefixed by +? And the sixth example because it has 7 digits, not 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the additional characters that you want to allow in data and then check if the vector has exactly 6 digits.

```
grepl('^\\d{6}$', gsub('[() -]', '', test_case))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Same logic implemented in `stringr` :

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(str_remove_all(test_case, '[() -]'), '^\\d{6}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
grepl('^[-\\(\\) ]*[[:digit:]]{3}[-\\(\\) ]*[[:digit:]]{3}$', test_case)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```